# Is it possible to add dropdown filter to an excel while exporting using python

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

Tried this block of code.
How to add a filter's in excel while exporting using python.
kindly suggest me a way to solve this problem.

```
    from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    def add_drop_down(file_path, file_name, row_total):
        print("adding drop down")
        wb = load_workbook("".join([file_path, file_name]))
        ws = wb['Daily Report']

        current_row = 2
        while current_row < row_total + 2:
            data_val_results = DataValidation(type="list",formula1="=='Daily Report'!C4:C100")
            data_val_status = DataValidation(type="list",formula1="=='Daily Report'!D4:D100")

            ws.add_data_validation(data_val_results)
            ws.add_data_validation(data_val_status)

            row_results = "".join(["C", str(current_row)])
            row_status = "".join(["D", str(current_row)])

            data_val_results.add(ws[row_results])
            data_val_status.add(ws[row_status])

            current_row += 1
        wb.save("".join([file_path, file_name]))

    dd = add_drop_down("C:/", 'Daily.xlsx', len(Piv2['Group']))
```

Comment: Sanjay Boga, could you share what you were expecting and what you are getting, or the errors you are receiving if you are receiving errors?